# railway deployemnt (taking too much time on page One Moment your app should be live soon)

Tags: node.js, deployment, railway.js

i have deployed my node Js project on railway through Github and it deployed successfully also shows in production log
npm WARN config production Use `--omit=dev` instead.

> apitwidleagent@1.0.0 start
> node index.js
> your server is running on port to 6499 finally
> mongoDB is connected

but its taking too much time on page when its say wait one moment your app should be live soon,its been around 30 mins passed and it still on waiting

i have check log but there is no error its loging my running messages
npm WARN config production Use `--omit=dev` instead.

> apitwidleagent@1.0.0 start
> node index.js
> your server is running on port to 6499 finally
> mongoDB is connected